# How to transfer files sequentially from one folder to another using apache camel?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

i have certain files in one folder:

abc.zip (optional)

def.zip(optional)

ghi.zip(optional)

I want to send it to destination folder sequentially.
 From destination folder they will be sent to 3rd party system.
So ,Suppose abc.zip is transferred to destination folder,unless it is picked by third party system def.zip should not be transferred to destination folder.

So,destination folder is like watch folder where i want to check  if previous file is present or not.If not then only send next file.

Is there any way to achieve this using apache camel?

Comment: What if after sending abc.zip, it will appears again in folder before def.zip will be sent ?

Comment: @c0ld no file will not appear again...each file will have unique name

Comment: if they are unique how you will know in what order route should consume them ?

Comment: @c0ld i have source folder where i have files sorted in some order

Comment: So i don't see problems here.  Just use "preSort" "sortBy" and "sort" properties in your purpose. More information [here](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, it sounds like you'd need to implement a `org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProcessStrategy` class and set that as the `processStrategy` on the file component. That way you can check the destination for any files which have an earlier name.

From the docs (emphasis added):

> A pluggable org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProcessStrategy
>   allowing you to implement your own readLock option or similar. **Can**
>   **also be used when special conditions must be met before a file can be**
>   **consumed**, such as a special ready file exists. If this option is set
>   then the readLock option does not apply.

Comment: How can he achieve "in some order" consuming using GenericFileProcessStrategy considering all files are with unique names ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't address that. There's `preSort` which can be applied to consumers which will do the ordering.